# Create hyperlink from cell contents in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to create hyperlinks based on the cells content in a user selected range of cells. I have gotten this far however when it runs it cycles through loop but does not create any hyperlinks.

```
Sub AcctHyperlink()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", "Select Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then

            WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Hyperlink.Add Anchor:=WorkRng.Cells(i, 1), _
            Adress:="https://example.com/" & WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value & "/search", _
            TextToDisplay:=WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information (and a badge!).  If my answer is helpful, please hit the up arrow; if my answer solves your problem, please also hit the checkmark to show it's the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** Nothing more than two typos and missing `CStr()` calls!  `Hyperlink` should be `Hyperlinks`, and `Adress` should be `Address`.  The code you have compiles fine because `Range.Item` returns a `Variant`, not a `Range`, so Excel can't flag such errors at compile time.  The following works on my Excel 2013 installation:

```
Option Explicit    '<--- always use this for more robust code

Sub AcctHyperlink()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    'On Error Resume Next  '<--- Omit for error checking
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", "Select Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Dim i as Long   '<--- Need this because of Option Explicit
    Dim addr as String  '<--- ditto
    For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            addr = "https://insight.metavante.org/opstopb1/OpstopServlet/Search?activityID=ViewProfileLnNote&activityType=note&activityTrgtID=undefined&activityAction=search&profileView=&accountNumber=" & CStr(WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value) & "&accountType=&subAccountNumber=&prcsGrpID=136&RelatedFIs=136&searchBy=account"
                ' Note: need CStr()
            '                            V--- "Hyperlinks"
            WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WorkRng.Cells(i, 1), _
            Address:=addr, _
            TextToDisplay:=CStr(WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value)
            '^--- "Address" two lines up
            '              ^^^^---- Need CStr()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response catching those typos. The code unfortunately is still is not creating hyperlinks. I am currently using Excel 2010, could that cause this problem?

Comment: Possibly.  Just noticed --- remove the "On Error Resume Next" from your code.  That's the reason it wasn't reporting errors at run time.  Then see what error you get.  I don't have Excel 2010 so unfortunately can't test it.  --- One other thought: assign the address first in a temporary string, then use that temporary string as the parameter to `Hyperlinks.Add`.  Always good to keep individual lines simple for ease of debugging.

Comment: OK - fixed!  The remaining problem was that you need `CStr()` around each use of `Value`.  I was testing with random letters I typed, but you are using numbers, right?  `.Value` is a numeric if the cell only has digits in it, so you need `CStr` two places (see code in edited answer) to turn those numbers into strings for `Address` and `TextToDisplay`.

Comment: Great, Thanks a ton for your help. I was not aware of the CStr().

Comment: Just change Adress by Address and Hyperlink by Hyperlinks and everything will be work well

Answer (score 0):

you must be change :

`Adress` by `Address` and 
`Hyperlink` by `Hyperlinks`

Comment: Abdellah, thanks for your work to help WolfReborn!  Since you have already posted an answer, would you please refrain from also posting your answer in comments?  As far as I know, the system will notify Wolf of your answer even without the comments.  Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure!  Glad you're here and helping people out!